# Why wasn't Fiona in human form in Shrek: Forever After?

Tags: shrek, shrek-forever-after

Why wasn't Fiona in human form? Rumpelstiltskin had the contract signed by Shrek costing his existence. Shrek didn't exist, which means that Fiona was always a human (unless at night when the curse took place) when she was imprisoned in the castle. However she is seen as a female warrior ogre in the tribe/clan.

Regarding that:

1. She escaped herself so she couldn't have a true love to kiss her (so as to become an ogre).
2. She did not turn human when it was daylight when Rumpelstiltskin was defeated.

Comment: The real answer is probably that the makers of that film forgot the plot of the first one...

Comment: @evilsoup: I don't think they forgot the plot of the first, especially considering that so much of the plot of 4 was based on changes to 1.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe that in Shrek: Forever After, Fiona wasn't ever seen during the day.  Shrek spent only a single day in that reality, starting at sunrise.  After the next sunrise, he would disappear.

He didn't encounter Fiona until after dusk, when the curse would transform her into an ogre.

At the end of the movie, he hadn't faded away (and thus the sun hadn't risen) completely before the contract was nullified.  Had the sun fully risen (and thus triggered her change to human) Shrek would have already faded entirely away.

More to the point, Rumplestiltskin, who adheres strictly to the letter of his word, promises to let "all ogres" go free in return for Shrek's surrender.  He specifically does not release Fiona, as she isn't "all ogre".  He points out that she's only half-ogre, being human during the day.

Ergo, the curse was still in place during this movie, and would have been broken at the climax, except that the entire world was invalidated simultaneously.

Comment: But why did the rest of the ogre clan accept her as one of their own,seemingly knowing her for a pretty long time.Wouldnt seem likely that she only came out at night for training/fighting etc

Comment: @THISISSPAAARRRTTTTAAA: The ogres seem to be nocturnal (which makes sense, given the typical mythology).  Perhaps she simply locks her door?

Comment: your right.. I completely disregarded mythology xD

Answer (score -3):

you misunderstood it. The reason why she did not transform at the end is because Shrek BROKE her curse again. Just like in the first Shrek where fiona fell in love and has been an ogre forever. Also Shrek entered in the ogre's place at NIGHT. That's why Fiona is an ogre.